# Save PDF file in Isolated storage for read/write operation in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

For my application I want to put PDF file into isolated storage for browsing the same pdf file as per
my requirement.

Is it possible to write PDF files in isolated storage?

This is my code:

```cs
var AppIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
var FileName = AppIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(FName);
string FilePath = uriAddress.LocalPath;
Uri FileDataa = new Uri(FilePath, UriKind.Relative);
var FileData = Application.GetResourceStream(FileDataa);

byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];      
int Count;        
while ((Count = FileData.Stream.Read(bytes, 0, 4096)) > 0) 
{
    FileName.Write(bytes, 0, Count);
}
FileName.Close();
```

Its only creating a file name inside the isolated storage with unknown format.
I also gone through this link  http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/save-pdf-file-to-local-storage/
but in windows phone8/8.1 no assembly supporting c1PdfViewer1.

Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: what do you mean by "creating a file with unknown format"?

Comment: After this code I can able to create a file with the same size and name what is my main file is contain, but in isolated storage when I tried to open this file its showing unknown format.

For checking isolated storage I am using IsoStoreSpy

Comment: @Prekshya you should open the original file and compare byte for byte vs the new file.  If all bytes are equal then the files are identical.